# Solaris 11 and vim F instead of end

Tags: vim, solaris, terminfo

I'm on Solaris 11

This is My .vimrc

```
set nohlsearch
set mouse=""
set paste
set showmode
set ruler
set clipboard=unnamedplus
setlocal cm=blowfish2
set nocompatible
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set term=dtterm
syntax on
imap <esc>OH <esc>0i
cmap <esc>OH <home>
nmap <esc>OH 0
nmap <esc>OF $
imap <esc>OF <esc>$a
cmap <esc>OF <end>
```

The key END of keyboard works fine

in command mode,but when i type I or A 
or a,for editing..type END and...it type F!
Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terminal description (for `dtterm`) doesn't include the special key that you'd like vim to recognize.  Since it's not in the terminal description, vim doesn't know what to do with the characters other than handle them as a command: **escape** from insert-mode, then **open** and insert **F**).

Here's what Solaris says for `dtterm`:

```
#     Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/lib/terminfo/d/dtterm
dtterm|CDE terminal emulator,
        am, mir, msgr, xenl, xon,
        colors#8, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, lm#0, pairs#8,
        acsc=``aaffggjjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~,
        bel=^G, blink=\E[5m, bold=\E[1m, civis=\E[?25l,
        clear=\E[H\E[J, cnorm=\E[?25h, cr=\r,
        csr=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr, cub=\E[%p1%dD, cub1=\b,
        cud=\E[%p1%dB, cud1=\n, cuf=\E[%p1%dC, cuf1=\E[C,
        cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH, cuu=\E[%p1%dA, cuu1=\E[A,
        dch=\E[%p1%dP, dch1=\E[P, dim=\E[2m, dl=\E[%p1%dM,
        dl1=\E[M, ech=\E[%p1%dX, ed=\E[J, el=\E[K, el1=\E[1K,
        flash=\E[?5h$<200>\E[?5l, home=\E[H, ht=\t, hts=\EH,
        ich=\E[%p1%d@, il=\E[%p1%dL, il1=\E[L, ind=\ED,
        invis=\E[8m, is2=\E\sF\E>\E[?1l\E[?7h\E[?45l, kbs=\b,
        kcub1=\E[D, kcud1=\E[B, kcuf1=\E[C, kcuu1=\E[A,
        kdch1=\E[3~, kf1=\E[11~, kf10=\E[21~, kf11=\E[23~,
        kf12=\E[24~, kf13=\E[25~, kf14=\E[26~, kf15=\E[28~,
        kf16=\E[29~, kf17=\E[31~, kf18=\E[32~, kf19=\E[33~,
        kf2=\E[12~, kf20=\E[34~, kf3=\E[13~, kf4=\E[14~,
        kf5=\E[15~, kf6=\E[17~, kf7=\E[18~, kf8=\E[19~,
        kf9=\E[20~, kfnd=\E[1~, khlp=\E[28~, kich1=\E[2~,
        knp=\E[6~, kpp=\E[5~, kslt=\E[4~, nel=\EE,
        op=\E[39;49m, rc=\E8, rev=\E[7m, ri=\EM, rmacs=^O,
        rmam=\E[?7l, rmir=\E[4l, rmso=\E[22;27m, rmul=\E[24m,
        sc=\E7, setab=\E[%p1%{40}%+%dm,
        setaf=\E[%p1%{30}%+%dm,
        sgr=\E[0%?%p1%t;2;7%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p3%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p5%t;2%;%?%p6%t;1%;%?%p7%t;8%;m%?%p9%t^N%e^O%;,
        sgr0=\E[0m, smacs=^N, smam=\E[?7h, smir=\E[4h,
        smso=\E[2;7m, smul=\E[4m, tbc=\E[3g,
```

There's no **`kend`** defined, and no `smkx` and `rmkx` capabilities defined to switch to/from keypad mode.  The mapping you're showing is for [*application mode*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#cursor_appmode) (which conventionally -- depending on the *terminal* would be done using smkx/rmkx).  An application mode special key would begin with <kbd>escape</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>, and as you see, none of the terminal description does **that**.  Given all of that, it would be interesting to see how you are exercising the bindings which rely upon application-mode.

Now... it's rather unlikely that you're using [**dtterm**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-dtterm) on Solaris 11.  That was the terminal emulator provided with CDE, which is not used much anymore.  It's more likely that you're using xterm or some imitation.  In that case, your best solution would be to install and use the terminal database from ncurses.

In a quick check of Solaris 11, I do see that they have a *variant* of [`xterm-256color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-256color), but it's been modified (and thus made less than usable): the value for `kend` is incorrect.  Looking closely, it seems that the Solaris developer made `xterm-256color` inherit from `xtermm` (or equivalently, from `xtermc`).  The latter is pointed out in the xterm FAQ *[What $TERM should I use?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_terminfo)*:

> Some people recommend using [xtermc](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xtermc). That is installed on Solaris. However, it does not match any xterm in current use. (Apparently it was written for an obsolete version on Unixware). ***The colors work, true, but the mouse will not, nor will the function keys***.